# Installing and running python unit tests within visual studio

Tags: python, unit-testing, anaconda, visual-studio-2019

I tried configuring unittest for Visual Studio Community Edition 2019 version 16.6.2.  I had no success with the Test Explorer finding my unit test.  I simply added a simple unit test using Add Python Unit Test from right-clicking on the project.  And it couldn't find the test_1.py file.

Then, I switched to pytest and Test Explorer found my unit test in test_1.py.  But, when I added any import statements to find my code in my project, it rendered the Test Explorer unable to find my unit test once again.

Next, I looked for a way to install nose unit testing under Visual Studio and it asked me to configure some settings file for which I could not find.

I have blank **init**.py files in all my source folders.

Anyway, can someone please suggest a unit test framework that does work within Visual Studio and isn't so hard to configure?  Perhaps even uploading a simple project with src files would be of help.  Please explain how to configure it.

For the time being, I may just try executing my tests from the commandline....I have used nose successfully from the commandline before....

I am using Anaconda Python 3.7.

Thanks,

Dan